# dynamically add a div tag and inside of div tag insert an loading gif image inside of ajaxStart function

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to display loading gif image dynamically in all HTML web pages?

```
var loading = $(' <div id="loading">  <img src="../img/loading%20(1).gif" id="loading-image" alt="Loading..." /> </div>');

$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
});
```

What is code for  inside of `.ajaxStart();` and `.ajaxStop();`?

Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to add the item

```
$( ".your-div-class" ).append( loading );
```

And [remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) to delete it.

```
$( "#loading" ).remove();
```

Final code should be:

```
var loading = $(' <div id="loading">  <img src="../img/loading%20(1).gif" id="loading-image" alt="Loading..." /> </div>');

$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    $( ".your-div-class" ).append( loading );
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
    $( "#loading" ).remove();
});
```

Comment: $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    $(".pageload").append(loading);     inside of ajaxstart funcrion there is no  ".append()" , it's not working. which  div class name  i used

Comment: you should put the div id or class that you want the loading to appear in.

Comment: is it same div id  like -->$("#loading").append(loading);

Comment: Do you want just to show or hide the tag? if so, you should do it with $('#loading').show() and $('#loading').hide().

Comment: there is no .show() and .hide() functions.  showing only .showDuration(),.showMethod(), etc

Comment: thanks,      but  i written code as follows  not working                      $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    $("#loading").show();
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
      $('#loading').hide();
  }); not working help me.......

Comment: Male jsfiddle and I will take a look

Comment: $(document).ajaxStart(function () {

    $('#loading').ajaxStart(function () {
        $(this).fadeIn();
         });});         
$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
    //$('#loading').hide();
   $('#loading').ajaxStop(function () {
       $(this).fadeOut();
      });}); is working but not properly

Comment: why double ajaxStart?

Comment: i used more ajaxcalls for all html pages

Comment: sorry, i dont understand. i think if you'll make jsFiddle example it will be much more understandable.